# in iMovie, does adding title at the start of a clip cuts the clip portion from there?

Tags: imovie

I am trying to learn iMovie and I have a question. Does adding title at the start of a clip cuts the clip portion from there?

Scenario:
Let us assume that i have a 50 seconds clip and I want to display a 3 seconds title Before the actual clip starts. if i drag a title from the titles section of the iMovie to the start of the loaded clip, will the initial 3 seconds of my clip be removed or will the clip be extended   resulting a clip of 53 seconds (50+3) ?

Comment: Putting this as a comment for now since I don't know iMovie specifically, but in higher end video editing packages, it depends on how you add it.  You can either add a title so that it goes over top of a video (in which case the video will still play underneath) or you can set it to play before the video.  I would go out on a limb to assume that iMovie also probably allows both options, even though it is very limited.

Comment: Yes, your guess is right. iMovie has both options and I know that already but my question is something else. What happens when I set the title to play before the video for, let's say'  5 seconds. Does it cut the actual video 'content' by 5 seconds or just extend the newly encoded video by 5 seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the title before the video and put the video after the title, it will extend the length.  If you put the title over the video, it will simply be placed over top of the first few seconds of video and the length will remain the same.